# Predict next time for repeating event with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a dataset for store inventory management. For every product I have the history of product Order of renewal. For example for a product A, I have:

A,last_time_of_renawal,volume_order,time_of_order
A,last_time_of_renawal1,volume_order1,time_of_order1

for every line, I have also other information like (category of product, sales number, stock_volume...)

How can I use this dataset and tensorflow (or other deep learning library) to predict the next time_of_order for a product knowing the last_time_of_order

Answer (score 1):

that is too broad of a question for StackOverflow. Try to specify it using this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
But essentially you want to do a regression on the delta between time_of_order and last_time_of_order. That's your y. Then you have your features using category of product etc (your x). 
Now you have a wide world of statistical analysis at your disposal.
If you insist on using deep-learning: Try setting up a "simple" neural network using a [youtube playlist](https://youtu.be/oYbVFhK_olY). When you succeed, you can try using your own data.

And you if you encounter problems... come back to StackOverflow with a specific programming question :) Have fun!